# PostgreSQL error "Relation does not exist" after trying to restore Sonarqube database

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, digital-ocean, database-restore

For a while now I've been trying to find a way to restore our sonarqube postgresql database, but I keep having this issue. Both our Sonarqube and the postgresql database are running in Docker containers, which are located on a droplet in Digital Ocean.

Making the backup is going fine, but when I try to restore I get the following error:

```
2020.09.22 12:57:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Error in NotificationService
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "notifications" does not exist
  Position: 40
### The error may exist in org.sonar.db.notification.NotificationQueueMapper
### The error may involve org.sonar.db.notification.NotificationQueueMapper.findOldest-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select uuid, data, created_at     from notifications     order by created_at asc     limit ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "notifications" does not exist
  Position: 40
```

It keeps happening for "notifications" only. I tried to test the backup restoer with only some users and with a whole project, and the funny thing is that I do actually see the users and the project EXIST in the database. Just somewhere during the restore something seems to be going wrong.

The way I do the restore is to copy a script to the sonar-db container which performs a full drop of the sonar DB. Then I create the db anew and I try to load my psql dump file with this command:

```
cat <psql.dump> | docker exec -i <container> psql -U sonar
```

The images we use for the containers are **sonarqube:latest** & **postgres:latest**

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is this:`select uuid, data, created_at     from notifications     order by created_at asc     limit ?`. It is being run before `notifications` is loaded by the restore. It is not a system query, it is some user built query.  The `limit ?` would seem to indicate it is a script/function/procedure. As a starting point, this behavior is often seen in `CHECK` constraints that use a function.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Your comment looks to me like a reasonable shot at an answer.